# Multiple connection from one user

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I created simple Express server:

[Code](http://4programmers.net/Pastebin/2873)

There is line:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

That runs routes.index function when I enter my site. This is code of it:

[Code 2](http://4programmers.net/Pastebin/2874)

The problem is: when I refresh my site, "connection" in logs is shown two times. When I refresh it again, three times and so on.
[image]

Can you tell me: why one site connect to server more than once? It makes a problem, because when server sends feedback, client get this message multiple times.

Comment: I think you have to show us how you're creating the server and setting the routes ?

Comment: @adeneo Mind you I gave a code